# how to implement smile detection in android?

Tags: android, camera

Is it possible to implement smile detection in android . I know that there FaceDetector class in android.In some samsung phone smile detection is possible.is it possible to implement in all devices?

Comment: yes it is. you should look for openCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OpenCV Smile Detector :**

It is possible to detect smile. There are many opensource projects. Here is one that might help you.

[repo](https://bitbucket.org/lordghost/smiledetector).

Comment: your link saying,Oops, you've found a dead link.please share the link of smileDetection,thnaks in Advance